# Can't get JQuery AJAX POST on WampServer localhost working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wamp, wampserver

I am developing a WordPress website on a localhost using WampServer.

I have a custom js file, `custom-js.js`, file located at `C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\my-theme\js`

When a user click on a vote up button, I want to send the product ID via AJAX to a PHP file where I can edit the vote count in my SQL database. I also want to display a message to the user. The PHP file is called `script.php` and is located at `C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\my-theme\js\ajax`

My code in the `custom-js.js` file looks like this:

```
$(function() {

        $(".product-vote-button-up").click(function(){
            var productID = $(this).attr('productID');      

            var request = $.ajax({
              url: "/ajax/script.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: {id : productID},
              dataType : 'json',
            });

            request.done(function() {
              $("#product-" + productID + " .item-product-footer-vote-container").html('Thanks for your vote!');
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        });

    });
```

This code would always give me an error message `localhost says: Request failed:error`

I am not sure if the way I am writing the path for `url:` is good and if it's the reason why I can't get a successful request. The path of my PHP script is relative to the path of the js file. Do I need to do any type of custom configuration to run AJAX on my local server?

Answer (score -1):

The line in the wrong direction. Use /ajax/script.php

If path http://localhost/mywebsite use /mywebsite/ajax/script.php

Comment: Changed line direction, didn't change the response. Still getting an error.

Comment: @LaGuille open Developer console, go to Network and see request. http://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art034

Comment: Okay so it's looking for `http//localhost/ajax/script.php`, but the script file isn't in this directory. Any ways to have the url path relative to the js file I am using?

Comment: @LaGuille If your domain http://localhost/wordpress/ use /wordpress/ajax/script.php or relative path ajax/script.php.